# how to make a bootable ubuntu from already installed ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system, bootable

I don't know this is a right question . But I want to know whether can I make a bootable Ubuntu for my friend from my already installed Ubuntu desktop ? I.e. I want to make a bootable copy of Ubuntu for installing to my friend PC . But I have a desktop which already contain Ubuntu OS . Any possible way to make a bootable Ubuntu from my already installed Ubuntu Desktop ?  Any software or tool can I use ?

Comment: This might be better suited to ask ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Don't know that you can just snake an already installed image off your drive.

What you could do however is download the latest Ubuntu Image from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), then find an old USB drive you have laying around and use [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) fancy utility.

PenDrive makes it super easy to format a USB drive into a bootable device with the image of your choice. BUT, note that a format of the drive is typical.

Hope this helps!